# Hide DZNEmptyDataSet on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using DZNEmptyDataSet with retry button for handling UIWebView when network is unreachable.
This is my code for adding button into UIWebView:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)buttonTitleForEmptyDataSet:(UIScrollView *)scrollView forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    NSString *text = @"Retry";
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:(state == UIControlStateNormal) ? @"#40C141" : @"#c6def9" alpha:1.0];

    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:textColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
}
```

This is my code for handing button tapped:

```
- (void)emptyDataSet:(UIScrollView *)scrollView didTapButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    self.failedLoading = NO;
    [self.gameDetailWv reload];
}
```

But the DZNEmptyDataSet doesn't hide (I think UIWebView was overlapped by DZEmptyDataSet view) when I tapped on button to reload UIWebView.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Oops I'm realize that my question is very stupid. All I must use is let my webview load current request instead of using [webview reload] method.
Sorry guys for my stupid answer.